# Building Apache QPID on Windows missing setup.py

Tags: c#, python, windows, apache, qpid

I am new to Apache Qpid, Cmake and Python.  I have successfully built Qpid on Debian and ran some of the tests.  I am now trying to build Qpid on Windows so that I can write a C# client, but something seems wrong.  When I run the cmake command it ends up giving me to following output:

```
Please wait while cmake processes CMakeLists.txt files....

C:/Program Files (x86)/Python330/python.exe: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Variable Name: BUILD_ACL 
Description: Build ACL enforcement broker plugin
Current Value: ON
New Value (Enter to keep current value):
```

I am trying to understand when setup.py should have been generated/downloaded.  I can't find it and I can't find any documentation that describes when it should have been generated or installed.  Also, somewhat off-topic, why did the cmake process start prompting me for BUILD_ACL and other configs?

I have ran cmake for both VS 2008 and 2010, using the following commands, and both yield the same output:

```
cmake -i -G "Visual Studio 9 2008" .
cmake -i -G "Visual Studio 2010" .
```

I am using the following file from Apache to build Qpid:
qpid-cpp-0.18.tar.gz

As you can tell from the log statements above I am using Python 3.3.0.

I understand that the setup.py is a file used by Python for installing components.  It appears that the cmake script is attempting to install something in the tests directory based on part of the cmake script I found by searching for setup.py.  I would think this is something that would either be supplied in the Qpid tarball or somehow generated as part of this cmake process.

All that said, I ended up holding down the enter key accepting all the defaults of cmake and it generated the solution file and project files.  I am able to open the resulting Qpid solution in VS2008 and build some of the projects.  So, that raises the question, why was the setup.py needed?

Answer (score 2):

Qpid user questions get good responses when asked at users@qpid.apache.org
The qpid developers are fairly responsive to the mailing list.

`cmake -i` does an interactive configuration. That's why it asks for all the variable values. `cmake` without the `-i` goes with the defaults. It is possible to answer "y" to variables that should be 'n' for your system, producing a build environment that won't work. Try without the `-i` to get things started.

Running cmake twice in the same directory with two different generators is generally a bad practice. In your case it will generate a *.sln* file and *.vcproj* files for VS2008, and it will generate a *.sln* file and *.vcxproj* files for VS2010. If you do in-source builds the files may look the same but they are not. After you've run both `cmake` commands then the files will continue to look the same.

Unpack the source tarball again and try `cmake` using an out-of-source build.

```
mkdir b32-vs2010
cd b32-vs2010
cmake -G "Visual Studio 2010" ..\qpidc-0.18
```

Directory *b32-vs2010* will have your 2010 solution and project files, and all the generated source files. It leaves the source directory clean and free of generated files.

This should run without a complaint about `setup.py`. If you continue to have trouble please take advantage of the users mailing list.